# finding the the sum of multiples of 3 and 5 between 1 to 1000 in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to learn awk by doing some Project Euler questions.

Here is my code. I am not sure why it hangs. please advise

```
$ awk '{ sum=0
> for (i=3; i<=1000; i++){
> if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) 
> sum+=i
> }
> print sum }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk`, much like `sed`, works on input either provided through `STDIN` or a filename.  You have provided no such input.

What you want is something like this:

```
$ echo | awk '{sum=0; for (i=3; i<=1000; i++){if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))sum+=i}print sum}'
```

Notice that I piped the output of `echo` (essentially just a newline) to awk so it can perform your loop at least once

Comment: Wow .... dint think of providing a dummy input .. was loosing my mind over this one .... thanks.

Comment: The whole thing could be done in the `BEGIN` block in this case without dummy input, a main block or an `END` block.

Answer (score 2):

Put the whole thing in a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { sum=0
    for (i=3; i<=1000; i++){
    if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) 
    sum+=i
    }
    print sum }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here

1. Awk normally processes a line at a time Except for the code in a BEGIN or END block
2. Awk can read from STDIN when attached to a pipe OR as SiegeX explains, when you give a fileName as input.

This should fix it for you.

```
$ awk 'END{ 
    sum=0
    for (i=3; i<=1000; i++){
        if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) 
        sum+=i
    }
    print sum 
}' /dev/null
```

/dev/null is a valid fileName, that contains no data. So the 'main' loop in awk is run.
Then program senses 'no more data, time to run the END block'

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you use a `BEGIN` block, you won't need dummy input.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I knew that. Less is more ;-).